Is proper distance an invariant quantity?
I read on the Wikipedia page for proper length that proper distance is a quantity that is the same for all observers. I am not sure what it means exactly.
I learned from this answer that proper distance between two circumferential radius $r_1$ and $r_2$ in Schwarzschild spacetime is calculated using
$$\Delta R= \int_{r_2}^{r_1}\frac{1}{\gamma\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}} dr.$$
(I would like to know how to derive this formula.)
Here the quantity $\gamma$ depends on how fast a distant Schwarzschild observer moves towards a black hole. For an ideal observer (Schwarzschild observer who is at rest in radial infinity), $\gamma=1$.
It seems to me that Schwarzschild observers travelling at different velocities will not agree on proper distance $\Delta R$?
Did I misunderstand anything?

Nowhere in the answer you linked to, do I see the author referring to proper distance.

The Wikipedia article you linked to, also states clearly that: "In a curved spacetime, there may be more than one straight path (geodesic) between two events, so the proper distance along a straight path between two events would not uniquely define the proper distance between the two events."

@Amit I am pretty sure $\Delta R$ is commonly known as "proper distance."

The equation says to multiply by gamma, so it certainly can't be Lorentz- invariant, can it? The whole purpose of gamma is to provide an adjustment for values that DO vary between inertial frames, like speed.

That integral for the radial distance does not appear in the Wikipedia article you cited. I'd like very much to see it, because proper distance always involves an inertial frame. I don't see how gamma gets in there. Gravitational length contraction?

The spacetime interval is an invariant distance-like quantity, if that's what you're referring to.

“proper distance provides an invariant measure whose value is the same for all observers” - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_length

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350952/133418
